# How to change options value by hover() or mouseenter function e.g

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

After spending hours of research, I hope somebody can provide me some insights.
I want to implement this **[sliderTabs](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/)** jQuery plugin.

The problem using this plugin is that the option `pauseOnHover` does not work, even though I downloaded the plugin branch which contains the desired option (still, it doesn't work).

Is there any way to implement stopping the slideshow while the mouse hovers the slider div?

I am calling the plugin like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = jQuery("div#sliderTabs").sliderTabs({
      autoplay: 1000,
      mousewheel: false,
      transitionSpeed: 1500,
      tabs: true,
      position: "top",
      pauseOnHover: true
    });
});
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `.sliderTabs(false, autoplay );` not quite sure if that is what you wanted to write, please clarify

Comment: im sry for that, i rather hope to demonstrate what im tryin to achive as to serve correct code ^^ hope you jQuery Pro's forgiving my poor explanation ^^

Comment: Have you checked your browser javascript console for any errors on that option, or can you verify by searching the string "pauseOnHover" if it's actually present in the source you downloaded?

Comment: no errors at all in my browsers console :-/ i manually put the "pauseonHover" part into the source js-file - it was actualy easy to locate:
https://github.com/lopatin/sliderTabs/pull/10/commits/46f87158f2013e8731f0609779a21c391d7821e8

Comment: please review whether `instanceAutoPlay` has an instance in line 228 of the plugin by adding a `console.log(instanceAutoPlay)` to your local copy.

Comment: ok, i get an uncaught refference error! instanceAutoPlay is not defined in my console! i guess we need some "var instanceAutoPlay = new instanceAutoPlay" somewhere? forgive me my basic knowledge ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your commits to the plugin on GitHub, i might have spotted a possible error.

Line 211:
`var instanceAutoPlay = setInterval(plugin.next, settings.autoplay);`

The var `instanceAutoPlay` instantiated inside the option's `if() {}`-statement.

Try to initialize the variable outside the function. Also add a `console.log()` there to check if it is actually called.

**EDIT:**
I tried it myself with a local copy, and it worked flawlessly.
My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var slider = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs({
        autoplay: 3000,
        mousewheel: false,
        position: "top",
        pauseOnHover: true
    });
});
```

No problems at all.
To verify, here is a paste of my copy of sliderTabs 1.1: http://pastebin.com/0QGywjRd

Comment: now with YOUR copy it works perfectly!! What you have changed? thanks man, great!!

Comment: I didn't change anything. Maybe your copy didn't actually include the added functionality.

Comment: omg!! the copy - paste FAIL-trophy is mine ... thanks again and much respect!

Comment: No problem, I'm on a very delicate jQuery / JavaScript project myself (: